# Solve never terminates with simultaneous equation set

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have the following set of simultaneous equations that I want to solve symbolically. The two unknowns are $a$ and $d$.

$a=\frac{c*(d/10)}{1 + (f/130) + (d/50)} - \frac{a}{1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80)}$

$d=\frac{1*c*(f/130)}{1 + (f/130) + (d/50)}-\frac{c*(d/10)}{1 + (f/130) + (d/50)}+\frac{a}{(1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80))}-\frac{d}{(1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80))}$

When I try and solve them with:

```
Solve[{d == (1*c*(f/130))/(1 + (f/130) + (d/50)) - (c*(d/10))/(
    1 + (f/130) + (d/50)) + a/(1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80)) - 
    d/(1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80)), 
  a == (c*(d/10))/(1 + (f/130) + (d/50)) - a/(
    1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80))}, {a, d}]
```

The program just says "running" for ages and never terminates.

What can I do to solve the system?

Thanks

Comment: Subtract lhs from rhs, take `Numerator[Together[...]]`, solve that, then maybe check that solution(s) cause no denominators in the original system to vanish.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the input, taking LHS from both sides of the top equation and then doing Together[] also results in "Running..." and no termination :(

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I got it working, when I subtracted the lhs from the RHS, if you write up your answer I will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
eqns = {d == (1*
        c*(f/130))/(1 + (f/130) + (d/50)) - (c*(d/10))/(1 + (f/
          130) + (d/50)) + a/(1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80)) - 
     d/(1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80)), 
   a == (c*(d/10))/(1 + (f/130) + (d/50)) - 
     a/(1 + (a/100) + (d/100) + (f/80))};
exprs = Numerator[Together[Subtract @@@ eqns]]

(* Out[4]= {-260000 a + 520000 d - 2600 a d + 26000 c d + 260 a c d + 
  13000 d^2 + 52 a d^2 + 260 c d^2 + 52 d^3 - 2000 a f - 2000 c f - 
  20 a c f + 7250 d f + 20 a d f + 305 c d f + 85 d^2 f - 25 c f^2 + 
  25 d f^2, 
 520000 a + 2600 a^2 + 13000 a d + 52 a^2 d - 26000 c d - 260 a c d + 
  52 a d^2 - 260 c d^2 + 7250 a f + 20 a^2 f + 85 a d f - 325 c d f + 
  25 a f^2} *)

Timing[solns = Solve[exprs == 0, {a, d}];]

(* Out[5]= {0.468003, Null} *)
```

One can now backsubstitute the solutions, via ReplaceAll, into the original system. Or perhaps only into a collection of all denominators in the original system. Those that give zero denominators might need more careful consideration, based on the underlying problem, as to whether they should be retained or discarded.